# How stack structure works with compound statements inside a function?

Tags: c, stack

I'm trying to learn c programming and can't understand how stacks work.

Everywhere I read I find that when a function is called stack frame is created in the stack which contains all the data for the function call- **parameters, return address and local variables.** And the stack frame is removed releasing the memory when the function returns.

But what if we had a compound statement inside the function which have its own variables. Is the memory for the local variables for block is also allocated inside the stack frame when the function call and released when it returns.

**Example**

```
int main(){
    int a = 10;

    if(int a<50){
        int b=9;
    }
    else{
        int c=10;
    }
}
```

Is the memory for *b* and *c* is allocated with *a*  when the function starts executing?
And deallocated when the function returns?

If so than there is no difference other than the visibility of the variable when declaring it in the beginning of the function or inside a another block in the function.

Please explain.

Comment: Usually, yes. But theoretically the two variables could also be allocated as the scope is entered and destroyed when the scope ends. It should not matter to the programmer.

Comment: Since neither `b` nor `c` are ever used, they're probably optimized out and never created.

Comment: @500: That is certainly true, but in practice the existence of the `goto` statement complicates the theoretical implementation you mention. (It's legal to jump into a block skipping over a declaration as long as the declaration isn't a VLA.)

Comment: The compilers I'm familiar with will allocate space for the inner scope objects at function entry - for a straightforward case like this, they'll allocate space for an additional `int` object at the beginning of the function, and that space will be used for either `b` or `c` depending on which branch is taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard doesn't specify how such things are to be implemented. The C standard doesn't even mention a stack! A stack is a common way of implementing function calls but nothing in the standard requires a stack. All such things are implementation specific details. For the posted code, the standard only specifies when the variables are in scope.

So there is no general answer to your question. The answer depends on your specific system, i.e. processor, compiler, etc.

Provided that your system uses a stack (which is likely), the compiler may reserve stack space for all 3 variables or it may reserve space for 2 variables, i.e. one for `a`while `b` and `c` share the other. Both implementations will be legal. The compiler is even allowed to place the variables directly in some registers so that nothing needs to be reserved on the stack.

You can check your specific system by looking at the generated assembly code.

Answer (score 1):

A C implementation may implement this in multiple ways. Let’s suppose your example objects, `a`, `b`, and `c`, are actually used in your code in some way that results in the compiler actually allocating memory for them and not optimizing them away. Then:

- The compiler could allocate stack space (by decreasing the top-of-stack pointer) for all of `a`, `b`, and `c` when the function starts, and release it when the function ends.
- The compiler could allocate stack space for `a` when the function starts, then allocate space (again by decreasing the stack pointer) in the middle of the function when space for `b` or `c` is needed, then release that stack space as each block ends.
- In a good modern compiler, the compiler is likely to analyze all the active lifetimes of the objects and find a somewhat optimal solution for using stack space in overlapping ways. By “active lifetime”, I mean the time from when the value of an object is set to the last time that value is needed (not the C standard’s definition of “lifetime”). For example, in `int a = f(x); … g(a); h(y); a = f(y); … g(a);`, there are actually two lifetimes for `a`, from its initial assignment to the first `g(a)` and from the assignment `a = f(y);` to the second `g(a);`. If the compiler needs memory to store `a`, it might use different memory for these two lifetimes.

Because of the above, what memory is used for which C object can get quite complicated. A particular memory location might be used for `a` at one time and for `b` at another. It may depend on loops and `goto` statements in your code. It also depends on whether the address of an object is taken—if the address is taken, the compiler may have to keep the object in one place, so that the address is consistent. (It might be able to get away without doing that, depending on how it can see the address is used.)

Basically, the compiler is free to use the stack, other memory, and registers in whatever way it chooses as long as the *observable behavior* of your program remains as it is defined by the C standard.

(The *observable behavior* is the input/output interactions of your program, the data written to files, and the accesses to volatile objects.)

Answer (score 0):

Your example as stated is not valid since you have no brackets in the if-else statement. However, in the example below all variables are typically allocated when the function is entered:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;

    if (a < 50) {
        int b = 9;
    } else {
        int c = 10;
    }
}
```

As mentioned by user "500 - Internal Server Error", this is an implementation issue.